# Are there any "lifecycle" events for Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

While working with Firebase (the realtime database) I'd like to know the following about the objects in the database:

- Whether an object exists at a path
- When an object is created at a path
- When an object is destroyed at a path

I can figure out some hacks for these. For example:

- Subscribe to `on('value')` events and download the whole (often huge) object.
- Create a separate "flag" value for each object in the database that gets modified when objects are created and destroyed.
- Listen for 'child_added', 'child_removed', etc. on a particular field inside of an object, that has the same lifetime as the object.

These get the job done in some specific circumstances but are pretty arbitrary and don't scale well.

Is there a way to achieve the above without having to either download the whole object or else creating a bunch of "book-keeping" entries in the database?

Comment: It's common to duplicate data and add additional to your database to satisfy your expected queries, without accessing too much data.  There aren't any hidden or secret operations - what you see in the documentation is your toolset.

Comment: Well I was hoping that someone more clever/familiar with Firebase had some trick using queries or something. Oh well. If the answer is that there is no solution then I’m happy to accept your comment as an answer if you post it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's common to duplicate data and add additional to your database to satisfy your expected queries, without accessing too much data. There aren't any hidden or secret operations - what you see in the documentation is your toolset.  It sounds like you're doing the right things already.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the web SDK (browser perspective), realtime updates (`.on`) are the proper way to get this type of data. The data should not be huge - it's called the "Realtime Database" bcs it's not intended to store large filetypes such as images and videos.

[Listen for value events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events)

> ```
> var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('posts/' + postId + '/starCount');
> starCountRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
>   updateStarCount(postElement, snapshot.val());
> });
> ```

Comment: I appreciate the answer but there are many use cases where even if the file is small (e.g. ~20k) you don't want to move the whole file around. For example, imagine a shared document with >30 users (my current situation). In that scenario you wouldn't want to pass the whole document around to everyone whenever someone modifies it slightly.

Comment: perhaps you could listen on a more specific level, i.e., a child node of that document?

Comment: Yes you can. One workaround is to listen to the value of a small child value that doesn't change and has the same lifetime as the parent, but that's pretty ad hoc and doesn't work well if you want generic ways to map your database objects to your client models.